# How to solve: Deployed nodejs app shows blank on Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, heroku

Working application on localhost. I used webpack and babel before deployed it but it shows up blank when I clicked on the heroku URL, index.html shows nothing. Here's the Build Logs and Logs --tail

```
-----> Node.js app detected

-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false

-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  >=6
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

       Resolving node version >=6...
       Downloading and installing node 13.3.0...
       Using default npm version: 6.13.1

-----> Restoring cache
       - node_modules

-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
       audited 22264 packages in 14.297s

       17 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details

       found 6 vulnerabilities (2 low, 3 moderate, 1 high)
         run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

-----> Build

-----> Caching build
       - node_modules

-----> Pruning devDependencies
       removed 2 packages and audited 22250 packages in 12.798s

       15 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details

       found 6 vulnerabilities (2 low, 3 moderate, 1 high)
         run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 78M
-----> Launching...
       Released v8
       https://xxxxxx.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

logs --tail HERE:
[image: heroku logs --tail]

Comment: Are you getting any error in the browser console when you open link?

Comment: Please follow the instructions provided here:https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

Comment: @Sunil No it doesn't show anything, empty cloud folder. This might work, trying it today :https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/app-works-locally-but-crashes-on-heroku-solved/36038/10

Answer (score 0):

I found out that my built static folder wasn't pushed onto heroku git after I ran my production script. Took the folder out of gitignore and everything works now. Cheers.